# get_header action not working

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-theming

I am trying to change the header template using the `get_header` action but it wont change anyway I try to do it.

Here is what I tried by adding this in functions.php:

```
function prefix_new_header() {
    return 'newtmpl';
}
add_action( 'get_header', 'prefix_new_header' );
```

I have in the theme folder a file called **header-newtmpl.php**

I’ve tried different priorities (1, 10, 99), but it doesn’t work.

Is there something I am missing? Thanks for any help!

You can try this in twentysixteen, if you want to test it.

Comment: The actions hooks don't return, the return is the filters hooks. Maybe you modify the header.php template. It's interesting the question! I need that too!

Comment: I am using `get_header()` in all the templates that need it (like index.php, single.php and so on...), with no modification.

Answer (score 0):

If you've already created a different header template named as `header-newtmpl.php` you can simply pass an argument to fetch the new header.

From `get_header();`

Change it to `get_header('newtmpl');`

where `newtmpl` is the name of new header and it will fetch the contents of `header-newtmpl.php` instead of `header.php`